# I to setup a simple calculator, but keeping getting number1=1 and number2=1 although i think i change in the body of the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, calculator

I need to put a simple calculator to work. The program is running but I keeping the same numbers as `number1 = 1` and `number2 = 1`

```
class Calculator:
  
    def __init__(self, number1=1, number2=1):
        self.number1 =  number1
        self.number2 =  number2

    def calculator(self):
        operationDict = { "*": self.multiplication(), "/": self.division(), "+": self.sumOf(), "-": self.subtraction()}
        while True:
            self.number1 = int(input("Enter a digit, 0 to 9: "))
            self.number2 = int(input("Enter another digit, 0 to 9: "))
            print("number1 is: ", self.number1, " the number2 is: ", self.number2)
            operation = input("Enter a +,-,/,*: ")
            if operation == "*":
                print(operationDict["*"])
            if operation == "-":
               print(operationDict["-"])
            if operation == "+":
               print(operationDict["+"])
            if operation == "/":
               print(operationDict["/"])
        
    def sumOf(self):
        osum = self.number1 + self.number2
        self.osum = osum
        return osum

    def subtraction(self):
        osubs = self.number1 - self.number2
        self.osubs = osubs       
        return osubs
  
    def division(self):
        odiv = self.number1 / self.number2
        self.odiv = odiv
        return round(odiv,2)
 
    def multiplication(self):
        omult = self.number1 * self.number2
        self.omult = omult
        return omult

oCalculator = Calculator()
oCalculator.calculator()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling your functions *before* you prompt for the numbers:

```
operationDict = { "*": self.multiplication(), "/": self.division(), "+": self.sumOf(), "-": self.subtraction()}
```

Instead put the functions themselves in the dict, and call them only after the numbers have been entered:

```
        operationDict = { "*": self.multiplication, "/": self.division, "+": self.sumOf, "-": self.subtraction}

...

            operation = input("Enter a +,-,/,*: ")
            if operation == "*":
                print(operationDict["*"]())
            if operation == "-":
               print(operationDict["-"]())
            if operation == "+":
               print(operationDict["+"]())
            if operation == "/":
               print(operationDict["/"]())
```

Note that the function gets called when the `()` operator is applied to it, so don't use `()` until you're ready to call the function!

The function can be written much more simply by avoiding the use of instance variables completely; instead just pass `number1` and `number2` directly to the operator functions.  If you use operator functions that require arguments (rather than passing them implicitly as pre-initialized instance variables), it's impossible to accidentally call them before you have the argument values!  And this lets you skip the step of defining your own wrapper functions; just use the built-in `int.__add__` etc.

```
def calculator():
    operation_dict = {
        "*": int.__mul__,
        "/": int.__truediv__,
        "+": int.__add__,
        "-": int.__sub__
    }
    while True:
        number1 = int(input("Enter a digit, 0 to 9: "))
        number2 = int(input("Enter another digit, 0 to 9: "))
        print("number1 is: ", number1, " the number2 is: ", number2)
        operation = input("Enter a +,-,/,*: ")
        if operation in operation_dict:
            print(operation_dict[operation](number1, number2))
```

Answer (score 0):

don't initialize the values of number1 and number2 as 1 in **init** method